# What to check for when buying an electronic component or module

Tags: components, datasheet, reliability, module, quality

### This has been raised as a canonical Q and A for future reference

How can I acquire electronic parts/items/modules and ensure that there is minimal risk of them being unsuitable for my project or design?

Answer (score 10):

1. Any electronic component or module you buy for a project or design should have a data sheet. By data sheet I mean a PDF (portable document format or equivalent) like this: -

[image]

2. Do not assume that the product will be OK based on marketing/sales claims without researching the fine detail in the data sheet. This is why you need a data sheet, so do your homework and ensure that what you think you need is matched by the technical details in the data sheet. Make sure you have the latest data sheet (see 3 below).
3. The data sheet is sometimes wrong so, if something appears not to make sense, double check that you have the latest issue of data sheet and, if in doubt about some parameter or other, you can always raise a question on this site to gain clarity.
4. Earlier revision data sheets are usually available and so, if the manufacturer updates it, this can be traced back to the point where the change was made. Always save the data sheet in your design file when you use a new part. On the other hand, web-based specifications have no historical traceability and can lead to confusion and mistrust should things go wrong. This can make you appear stupid or careless and, won't provide the evidence that can cover you should there be customer dissatisfaction or legal problems.
5. The manufacturer of the part should be reputable but, as we know, new part manufacturers entering the market may not have gained a significant reputation. So, this may be hard to establish and, you have to be cautious. A lot of confidence can be gained by reading and understanding the data sheet of the part.
6. The supplier/shipper must be reputable for the type of goods they are handling (namely electronic parts) and, they should provide links to the manufacturer's data sheet (1). How do you know that some unmentionable supplier hasn't mishandled the goods and damaged them? I'm thinking ESD and water damage here but, there are probably other ways "unseen" damage can occur.
7. Watch out for fake parts – if the price seems too good to be true then maybe consider that the parts might be fake or possibly failed items underhandedly acquired by some disreputable supplier
8. Decide what you need to buy - don't assume that any old resistor, capacitor, transistor, or op-amp is going to work – think about what your final expectations are and, where things can go wrong (such as drift or basic output inaccuracies). You can't expect a supplier to be held responsible for you choosing a part that you haven't thought through sufficiently. This is what design is about - it's not about guessing that this or that will do so, do your homework (or pay the cost).
9. If you buy from a source selling unbranded goods you are taking a risk and, quite possibly, you will pay more (due to you wasting your own time) in the longer run so, how much do you value your time?
10. The component may be available from more than one manufacturer, in which case it is worth looking at the other datasheets as there could be some parameter which is better for your purposes in the product from someone else.

I'll probably think of a few more things to add as time passes by.

Comment: yeas, If they are cheap and you have time buy some and try some, you might get a bargain, you might get cheap junk.

Comment: I have a couple of red flags for datasheets: 1. If the datasheet is several years old and still has *Preliminary* on it (assuming you got the latest copy from the manufacturer website). 2. If the datasheet is *very poorly* translated - although this was quite common in the past (and a source of great amusement on occasion) it simply should not happen with newer components.

Comment: A significant proportion of datasheets from some geographic areas in some product categories are suspect. eg when I was involved in specifying LEDs in 1 million plus quantity I was "keen to be sure that the datasheets were meaningful". I found that finding some unique-ish phrase in a datasheet and websearching for it would often turn up the datasheet they had copy and pasted and sometimes altered and often a number of other manufacturer's versions and with some more checking  often the reputable original. A shonky datasheet does not guarantee a shonky product, but it's a useful guide.

Comment: These 9 points are all true, but none of them address the question of an OP that already bought an item unfit with some of these points above, and now OP needs some help for using it. Sometimes there are questions here from people that need help in using these cheap chinese things. Something that can be a real bargain for an expert professional that can solve all the upcoming questions himself may not be a bargain for other persons. Item 9 is not very well understood by poor people who lives in undeveloped countries - their main concern is, first, second, and third places, price.

Comment: @mguima this is an EE site and EE good practice is to always buy from a reputable dealer sourcing a recognized brand component that has a data sheet. There are many questions from hobbyists who have bought stuff from disreputable sources selling stuff of indeterminable quality from unknown sources and this Q and A applies to them. If you buy something that doesn't have adequate supporting documentation and provenance you can't expect miracles and, in the main you can't expect a promising answer from this site.

Comment: I understand all yours points and I agree with you. But they're useful for professionals sourcing components for industrial use, buying at wholesale. These points doesn't solve the problem of an OP that bought something in retail, got questions that he/she is unable to solve, and end up posting questions here. I see clearly that the focus of EE.SE is not hobbysts' questions, but, as I see the posters' side, I would suggest that EE.SE could have one of those: a) a kinder way of saying to OP that those posts don't belong here; OR b) a tag (or anoter SE.EE) for this kind of question.

Comment: @mguima We have a "be nice" policy. It doesn't always get well observed, sadly. The site is intended for professionals and amateurs / hobbyists.  It can be hard to reconcile the wide range of experiences. | The site intentions do not allow certain classes of questions (shopping, consumer repair without analysis, ...) but in most cases we are hopefully super useful and helpful.