# I need help with making a ground loop noise isolator

Tags: transformer, audio, noise, ground-loop

I want to build a ground loop noise noise isolator for 3.5 mm audio jack.
After some research online I found multiple circuit diagrams centered around using audio 1:1 transformers to isolate each channel. The diagrams were quite different, some featuring capacitors, resistors and diodes. Due to my rather limited knowledge of electrical engineering, I can't figure out how to build mine.
This is the transformer I plan on buying (its the only 1:1 transformer I can find in my country): https://www.tme.eu/ro/details/tr-1_1/transformatoare-pcb/
This is my current design:[image]

Would this work? If not, what would i need to change/add. A explanation would be very appreciated since I also want to learn why is each component need.
Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Looks fine to me (though I can't comment on the transformer itself)

Comment: You would need two transformers - one for the Left channel, and one for Right.

Comment: Yeah, those are meant to be two transformers with the ground wired together, blame my drawing skills in paint :D. The thing I'm worried about is the impedance of the transformer. A popular one I see is EI14. That one has 600 ohm vs 280 of the one I'm planning to use.

Comment: [What to check for when buying an electronic component or module](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/504044/what-to-check-for-when-buying-an-electronic-component-or-module).

Comment: Try a car audio shop. These kind of audio transformers are often marketed as "ground loop isolator" for car audio.