# How to identify duplicate vs original FETs

Tags: transistors, mosfet, power-electronics, motor-controller, powermosfet

I am really confused about this topic. Wheather it's ok to use duplicate MOSFETs or not.

Say for example my application requires to handle upto 20 amperes of motor current.

- Is it ok to use 100A or even more ampere of duplicate or Chinese MOSFETs.
- Or it's good to use only original MOSFET even with lower current specification.

Which one is better, and how can we identify whether a MOSFET is original or duplicate. Because duplicate MOSFETs will also work same like the original one, right?

Comment: "Is it ok to use a 100 meter long rope to tie an elephant?" That kind of depends on how thick the rope is, yeah? So how does this question make any sense without a specific part in mind? There will be a maximum current spec in the datasheet and that's all that matter.

Comment: What are "Chinese MOSFETs"? What does the datasheets say, how does the "duplicate's" parameters compare to the original MOSFET's parameters? Can the duplicate's datasheet **be trusted**? *Because duplicate MOSFETs will also work same like the original one right?* That depends on who you ask.

Comment: Don't use fake parts. In doing so you encourage a fake industry.

Comment: [What to check for when buying an electronic component or module](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/504044/what-to-check-for-when-buying-an-electronic-component-or-module).

Comment: Actually what I am trying to say is, some seller sells a MOSFET (say stp80nf70) for 30INR whereas some other seller sells for 150inr. So what I consider was 30inr was a duplicate and 150inr was a original one. Am I wrong? Does any other way to identify or to confirm duplicate mosfet.

Answer (score 0):

A FET is a FET. A FET has more parameters than just maximum drain-source current. If all parameters are acceptable for your case, you can use it.

It is another question, whether you trust the datasheet/manufacturer or not. If a product does not fulfill its specification, than legal actions are possible against them.