# Connecting LORA SX1278 1W to Arduino UNO (LORA 5V Supply voltage but 3.3V communication voltage)

Tags: arduino, lora

I bought this LORA modules: https://aliexpress.com/item/32791508935.html
in the datasheet it says that the module needs a power supply voltage of 5V but the communication level is 3.3V.
I've searched the web on bidirectional level shifters like this one: https://www.aliexpress.com/item/32713594384.html?spm=a2g0s.9042311.0.0.4a174c4dCJFkbm but in the connection examples the power supply voltage in the lower part is also 3.3V like this example: https://cdn.sparkfun.com/assets/learn_tutorials/1/4/7/LogicLevelFixed.png
And I can't find any information on how I can connect the LORA Module to the arduino throw a bidirectional level shifter.

Thanks for your time and help.

Comment: [What to check for when buying an electronic component or module](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/504044/what-to-check-for-when-buying-an-electronic-component-or-module).

Comment: I have the datasheet and all the information I just don't know how to connect the level shifter if the supply voltage in the 3.3V communication part is the same as in the 5V communication part.

Comment: Please link the data sheet.

Comment: http://www.ebyte.com/en/downpdf.aspx?id=108

Comment: I assume you are aware that operating this 1W module requires at least a ham radio license in most countries. And even if you have one, you will need to carefully control the output power and reduce transmission duration and frequency to stay within the link budget.

Comment: @Codo Yes I know. I own a Ham radio license as well as a baofeng uv-5r 1W I had to get the license when I got the baofeng.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This type of level shifter is quite popular and well documented/proven: -

[image]

This one is a two channel and the one below is a single channel: -

[image]

They can work with IIC, SPI or regular TTL level logic signals.

They are fully bidirectional.

Comment: So that means that I do not have to worry if my device uses 5V voltage supply and 3.3V communication voltage, I just need to give a 3.3V reference that can be provided by the 5V device like an arduino in this case, right ?

Comment: Yes, you can derive the 3.3 volts from a 5 volt source. Make sure the data with the higher value voltage is on the drain side of the MOSFET (as shown in the pictures).

Comment: Thank you so much