# What is the potentiometer for on ultrasonic module JSN-SR04T-V3.0?

Tags: arduino

[image]

I bought an ultrasonic module. It works fine. But I'd like to know how the pot on the module works.
Thank you.

Comment: refer to the datasheet for the module

Comment: What does the datasheet say and why didn't you link it in the question? "*No datasheet? No sale!" See [What to check for when buying an electronic component or module?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/504044/what-to-check-for-when-buying-an-electronic-component-or-module).

Comment: Where did you buy it? Didn't it come with manual, datasheet or instructions?

Comment: @Justme I bought it from aliexpress https://tinyurl.com/yxn8nxj7

Comment: Why not ask from where you bought it?

Comment: @justme I've sent the request for datasheet/manual but no reply.

Comment: It's not a pot, it's a variable inductor or transformer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Internet says it is an inductor tuning frequency of sensor to 40kHz.  Do not adjust.

Part number is probably [K4000001](http://www.prowave.com.tw/pdf/Transformer.pdf) from Pro-Wave Electronics with an variable inductance of 10.6 mH at operating frequency of 40.0 kHz.

[image]

[image]