# 2812B LED Power Injection

Tags: power-supply, voltage, led

I'm building a TV Ambilight using a Raspberry Pi and 2812B LED strip. First draft schematic below.

Few questions:

1. I intend to keep the strip connected and bend them around the TV and solder power injection into all four sides. Should I cut the 5V trace (highlighted in yellow on the schematic zoom) where I'm adding power injection or leave them connected? What's the impact of this choice?
2. Is it safe to daisy chain a few 5 lead Wago connectors for the power distribution?
3. Similar to #2, is it safe to connect the resistor, capacitor, and inline fuses via Wago connectors?
4. I'm planning on using 4 amp slow blow fuses on the 3 amp sections and 6 amp slow blow fuses on the 5 amp sections - is this appropriately sized?
5. Is 18 AWG sufficient? I calculated the voltage drop and it's on the order of a few percent for the length of wire I'm running. I've read these LEDs exhibit the same brightness from ~4.2-5V
6. Any concerns with powering the Pi, HDMI-to-AV, and HDMI Splitter from the same power source as the LEDs?
7. Is the capacitor sizing and location sufficient/correct, or would you recommend adding a capacitor at each injection point?

Thank you!

[image]

Schematic Zoom on LEDs:

[image]

Comment: Data sheet for the LED strip please.

Comment: I'm not sure one exists. Here is the LED strip: https://www.amazon.com/CHINLY-Individually-Addressable-Waterproof-waterproof/dp/B01LSF4Q00

Comment: [What to check for when buying an electronic component or module](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/504044/what-to-check-for-when-buying-an-electronic-component-or-module)

Comment: The LED itself is fairly ubiquitous. Here is its data sheet: https://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/datasheets/WS2812B.pdf 

As for the strips, they're sold by various Chinese suppliers on Amazon - I've yet to see a data sheet for one. I would love the opportunity to purchase 2812b LED strips with a data sheet, but this is what I've got.