# Can someone help me design an expandeable led strip system

Tags: led-strip, led-driver

I want to make an open source expandable system to control WS2812B 5m 60 ip30 (or higher pixel density) led strips. Im going to be using about 40 meters which is about 2400 leds in total but all the controllers I can find have a max pixel count of 2048. Is their a way I could have two controllers take 2 strips each and somehow link them together so its controlled as one strip? Could I reliably use and API to do this or is their some better hardware i could use? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[LED strips](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/33023954212.html?spm=a2g0o.cart.0.0.1df33c00elqX2E&mp=1)

[LED controllers](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/32702161116.html?spm=a2g0o.detail.1000014.8.691111aeFxRtho&gps-id=pcDetailBottomMoreOtherSeller&scm=1007.13338.183346.0&scm_id=1007.13338.183346.0&scm-url=1007.13338.183346.0&pvid=eb9e6b95-656b-4d69-b812-f75175d01ec6&_t=gps-id:pcDetailBottomMoreOtherSeller,scm-url:1007.13338.183346.0,pvid:eb9e6b95-656b-4d69-b812-f75175d01ec6,tpp_buckets:668%230%23131923%230_668%23808%234093%23744_668%23888%233325%2320_3338%230%23183346%230_3338%233142%239889%231_668%232846%238116%23973_668%232717%237563%23570_668%231000022185%231000069217%230_668%233422%2315392%23911)

Comment: You have linked to AliExpress ad pages instead of datasheets. Most likely there are none so you're buying 2400 LEDs with no specifications and hoping they'll all work. This is not advisible. See [What to check for when buying an electronic component or module](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/504044/what-to-check-for-when-buying-an-electronic-component-or-module).

Comment: You could have one controller control the other over I2C, SPI, or RS-485

Comment: The power traces do not function beyond 5m due to trace resistance. Try again.