# Using Buck Converter as Solar Charge Controller ? (see pic)

Tags: battery-charging, buck, lithium-ion, solar-charge-controller, bms

[image: Diagram]

Can I charge Li-Ion safely by connecting PV Panels to a CC CV Buck Converter then through BMS to a 3S3P batteries?

This is basically a plan for a very small solar powered device that takes in solar power (30 Wp), simultaneously charging batteries and powering the device for a few hours during the day (as long as buck's output voltage > battery voltage) and use the battery when the sun is out (battery voltage > buck's output voltage). The device/load (3W) is to be powered continuously.

Please let me know of any of your concerns, especially in regard to hazards and references.

Note:

- [The CC CV Buck Converter (connects PV to BMS)](https://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_from=R40&_trksid=p2047675.m570.l1313&_nkw=DC%20CC%20CV%208A%20Buck&_sacat=0), [some tests XL4016](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=emLLK32S3vE), and [datasheet XL4016](http://www.xlsemi.com/datasheet/XL4016%20datasheet.pdf)
- [The CV Buck Converter (connects BMS to Load)](https://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_from=R40&_trksid=p2334524.m570.l1313&_nkw=DC%20XL4015%205A%20sink&_sacat=0&LH_TitleDesc=0&_osacat=0&_odkw=DC%20XL4015%205A%20sink%27), [some tests XL4015](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8cRmGNmqRYc), and [datasheet XL4015](http://www.xlsemi.com/datasheet/XL4015%20datasheet.pdf)
- [The 3S3P BMS](https://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_from=R40&_trksid=p2334524.m570.l1313&_nkw=Balanced%203S%2040A%20BMS&_sacat=0&LH_TitleDesc=0&_osacat=0&_odkw=Balanced%2040A%20BMS)
- The PV Panels Voltage and Amperage are as measured while connecting them directly to load, not open circuit.

Please let me know if you need more information that hasn't been shown here or of whatever I am doing wrong, thank you

Comment: Data sheet links to the modules are required. Links to pee-bay (et al) means that you are considering buying from a source that is not well documented or reliable. Think again is my advice.

Comment: I added the datasheet to the ICs, but havent found any for the modules, but i found someone testing them on youtube, will add them here too.
Will oversizing help reliability for this case?

Comment: Nobody's going to look at youtube videos. Data sheets are what are needed: [What to check for when buying an electronic component or module](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/504044/what-to-check-for-when-buying-an-electronic-component-or-module).

Comment: If there is no data on the modules, how can anyone say anything about their suitability for any purpose?

Comment: Hopefully from someone having experiences using these modules and have read of the datasheets. In the meanwhile, i will continue looking for the datasheet or any alternatives that have.

Comment: Main issue (I think) is that a BMS is NOT designed to be a charger. It prevents gross excess conditions and may do balancing BUT is not designed to do proper CCCV charhing and charge termination. (SOME BMSs may have proper charging functions as well but its rare). || A "proper" charger will do CC charge to usually 12.67V, then CV charge to say Imax/4 say THEN fully remove charge voltage. A BMS will usually leave Vmax on battery indefinitely. Battery WILL die.

Comment: thank you, so, for the least, i should've to put a 12,6V triggered relay between the charging buck converter and BMS so the charge will be terminated completely. This may not charge to 100% due to termination will occur and will not proceed to CV phase, but it will prolong battery life, am i correct?

Answer (score 1):

It's probably safe because it won't likely work as the Buck charger will probably collapse the PV voltage to very inefficient low voltages.

A MPPT controller will hunt for the MPT by matching load impedance to the PV source for any solar condition. Max Sun each PV is Zmpt=Voc/Isc=17V/0.6A.

Also, this block diagram is rather simple and leaves a lot of specs out.

Comment: Thank you!
so will it not work or will it work but inefficiently?
What other information would you need me to put in it?

Comment: won't likely work unless it has a soft start with MPT regulation. CC mode from a PV?  impossible without impedance matching and a current source is high impedance.

Comment: What does soft start do? In this case, I'm using CC to cap current flows, even without CC the max current the PV can possibly put is 17/12.7*0.6A= 0.8A x3= 2.4A, assuming 100% efficiency, I guess that wouldn't hurt the 3P battery. Is impedance matching mandatory for charging or will it increase efficiency?

Comment: @yuda There are two requirements: MPT (maximum power transfer) regulation *and* soft start. The MPT regulation is a primary requirement, once you got that taken care of, soft start should be easy. In a nutshell: buck converter is OK but it won't work by itself: it needs to be in an MPT control loop. You also seem to think like getting better efficiency is just a bonus. Not at all: in this application it's critical, since a buck converter by itself will tend to run the panels at 1-5% efficiency. And since panels are expensive, getting maximum power transfer is essential, else you're wasting $$$

Comment: I mentioned Match Impedance, and when done from the startup means "soft start" is guaranteed but only if sufficient power to regulate V. I didn't show how, just that

Comment: Hi, so I made the device in Aug'20 and it's been running well since. It went off several times due to rain in Dec'20 and Jan'21 (wet season here nov-apr) and I took the opportunities to check the batteries voltage. All 3.66V, so I think they're fine.

And I found this pub
https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Comparison-of-output-power-with-and-without-MPPT_tbl2_273594839 . the wattage is similar to what I have, and using MPPT shows an increase in efficiency (<10%) but doesn't it imply that I can do away without?