# How does increasing voltage to a motor affect the power and current usage?

Tags: voltage, power, current, motor, brushless-dc-motor

Using [this motor](https://au.banggood.com/4X-Racerstar-Racing-Edition-2212-BR2212-920KV-2-4S-Brushless-Motor-For-350-380-400-Frame-Kit-p-1083198.html?gmcCountry=AU&currency=AUD&createTmp=1&utm_source=googleshopping&utm_medium=cpc_bgcs&utm_content=frank&utm_campaign=frank-ssc-aug-all-1129-v2&ad_id=400492522952&gclid=Cj0KCQjwk8b7BRCaARIsAARRTL7gPjKhEsxUTrRcEY1C-EE28w8q77SBrnuHwCnzfbpUQ_sA8rrVCp0aAvpNEALw_wcB&cur_warehouse=CN) as an example, which is rated for 7.4 to 14.8 volts.

When the voltage is increased (from 7.4 to 14.8) to the motor, how does this affect the power and current usage?

My understanding/guess is:

1. Torque increases
2. Power consumption increases
3. Current stays relatively similar

Using the performance data in the image below (performance data for the same example motor given above, which is data at 11.1v), is it possible to calculate how much the motor would perform at a different voltage?

[image: Motor performance data at 11.1v]

Comment: voltage most directly relates to RPM, the rest depends on what the motor's doing.

Comment: A proper data sheet is required. See this: [What to check for when buying an electronic component or module](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/504044/what-to-check-for-when-buying-an-electronic-component-or-module).

Comment: Completely unloaded, the torque increase may be minimal. Therefore current increase is minimal (maybe 30% for doubling voltage). Loaded, it all depends how torque varies vs speed. For example, a propellor, torque varies as speed squared, so double voltage = 4x current and 8x power.