# How to insert copper coil to output terminal?

Tags: circuit-analysis, wire, induction

I recently purchased a cheap induction heater circuit from ebay. Upon receiving I tried inserting the copper coil to the output terminals but it’s too small. I tried unscrewing the screws on the top but nothing happened. I have no idea if I’m doing something wrong and would like a second opinion. [image]

Comment: Just stick smaller gauge wire into the terminal block and connect your coil wires to that.

Comment: Site rule: *Questions on the use of electronic devices are off-topic as this site is intended specifically for questions on electronics design.* - and this means that unless you can provide a datasheet and schematic for the device you purchased we're all in the dark and having to guess. I wouldn't recommend buying electronic modules without decent supporting data and I wouldn't recommend buying stuff from ebay. [What to check for when buying an electronic component or module](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/504044/what-to-check-for-when-buying-an-electronic-component-or-module)

Comment: https://www.ebay.com/itm/120W-5V-12V-Low-Voltage-ZVS-Induction-Heating-Power-Supply-Module-w-Heater-Coil/124229420607?hash=item1ceca6863f:g:3tgAAOSwVpRe1KTs   Maybe ?

Answer (score 1):

Put the wires on an anvil, and flatten them with a hammer. They'll get slightly wider and not as tall and should then fit in the connector.

Answer (score 0):

Loosening the screws in the terminal block will allow the wire clamps to be pushed up, so you can insert the wires - loosening the screws won't (usually) pull the wire clamps up.  After inserting the wires, tighten the screws.