# How long can you power a solenoid? Is heat an acceptable way to check?

Tags: power, solenoid

I am wondering how long you would expect a standard electromagnetic solenoid like [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07QTKL4FV) to be able to be switched on? Any first hand experience would be appreciated.

[image: Image of solenoid from the Amazon link]

If there is no data on this - is it safe to turn it on and wait until it heats up? And then use just under that time for the future? In other words - if it doesn't get noticeably hot, does that mean it is fine to run it that long?

Comment: The datasheet is where you will find that information. "No datasheet? No sale!" There's a reason that Amazon is cheaper than the quality suppliers.

Comment: Based on the size and power, I would say it is not rated for continuous duty, intermittent only.

Comment: it's going to produce 12W of heat if operated at full power, depending on the environment it may be able to operate full time.

Comment: [What to check for when buying an electronic component or module](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/504044/what-to-check-for-when-buying-an-electronic-component-or-module).

Answer (score 1):

Solenoids like this in data sheet should have two different value of current. For move, current bigger, for hold, smaller. your example don't have those parameters. Ask the seller. If it is made not for commercial or industrial use, there is only way to find out is experiment.