# Servo motor signal voltage vs "working" voltage

Tags: arduino, voltage, servo

I'm looking at a few servo motors (on Amazon.)

Typically the "Working Voltage" is 6-7.4V. I can supply that with a power supply but what can I do about the signal? Can I just feed it the 5V PWM from an Arduino? Sadly there's no other voltage mentioned on the listing; do they have to match, or be at least the minimum of the working voltage, in this case 6V?

I can't find the specification sheet for most of them outside Amazon; but I assume the question is more about my understanding of servos than this particular one.

Edit: Yes, they take a PWM signal; [ground, +, signal] sort of connector.

Comment: [What to check for when buying an electronic component or module](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/504044/what-to-check-for-when-buying-an-electronic-component-or-module)

Comment: Are these even hobby style servos which take a PWM command, and not some other sort of servomotor?  At any rate, questions about devices without specifications are not on topic here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most hobby servos will work with a 5 V PWM signal (and I know from experience the Hitec HS-311 and a few others will even work with a 3.3 V signal), *but only specifications will give certainty*.

Try googling the servo brand and type, and see if specs can be found. If you can't find specs, consider buying an other servo that does come with specs, or take the gamble.

Comment: It's not even clear that the devices in question are *hobby* servos taking a PWM command vs some very different type of servomotor

Comment: Where am I saying they are?

Comment: Your answer addresses hobby servos with an implicit assumption of relevance

Comment: Oh please. I wrote a statement that is true, in an attempt to help. All the "implicit assumptions" you may see are yours alone, and not mine.

Answer (score 1):

Sure but only spend what you can afford to lose.

Or look around for better specs usually at the bottom of the page on Amazon. [https://www.amazon.com/KeeYees-Holder-Bracket-PCA9685-Controller/dp/B07KR1RP5K/ref=sr_1_20?dchild=1&keywords=servo+motor&qid=1609677105&sr=8-20](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07KR1RP5K)

Comment: What am I looking for in this particular case? I see "Operating Voltage Range: 4.8V～6.0V" which is again a range and nothing else about signal/pwm voltage. I can only assume I can feed it with 6V and get away with 5V on the pwm - but is that correct?
(in my case I need bigger servos that have higher voltage requirements)