# Using discharge protection, BMS and balance charging?

Tags: battery-charging, lithium-ion, discharge, bms

I am building a small high quality headphone amp which needs power supply +/-7V up to +/-17V. According to the manual it uses maximum 200mA.

I like to use 2 x 3 16340 rechargeable lithium batteries because they are relative small.
I think it is necessary to make sure the batteries are not discharged too low. This is why I think about using a BMS (battery management system). I plan to use two of these BMS:

[image]
[image]

To charge the batteries I think about using a RC hobby balance charger for 6S charging which I will connect when needed.

I will never use the amplifier while it is charging. There will be a switch which connects the batteries either to the amp or to the charger.

For the balance charger I need to connect all individual batteries to the charger. And all the individual cells are connected to the BMS.

Now my question is: **Is it ok when all cells are at the same time connected to the BMS and connected to the balance charger? Or do I have to disconnect the cells from the BMS when I charge them with the external balance charger?**

Or what are the alternatives? Is there another easy way to make sure the cells are not discharged below a certain voltage?

Or should I charge the batteries just by applying 12.6V, 500mA to the BMS and let the BMS handle the charging?

About the BMS in the picture: I think about using that model because I could buy it easily and it's cheap. I looked at big electronic distributors and I didn't find any BMS in their shops.

Comment: [What to check for when buying an electronic component or module](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/504044/what-to-check-for-when-buying-an-electronic-component-or-module)

Comment: Hard to say from what you've posted but generally a charger expects to have ONLY the batteries connected to it and nothing else. And as many people have said in many answers, a BMS is not a charger. You must use a proper charger with these batteries.

Comment: Thanks @Andyaka That brings up the question: Where can I buy a quality BMS with datasheet?

Comment: Unfortunately this isn't a shopping recommendation site. For most pros, you would choose a chip and design it onto a circuit board. If you can find a module and it has a comprehensive data sheet and it looks like a quality part sourced through a reputable distributor then I might consider buying it but, if I can't determine that, I would look at designing a PCB. Would I take a risk with some cheap pee-bay or shamazon part - I might but, if it didn't work properly and I wanted to debug it, I'd be stuck and, so would anyone on SE if I raised a question about it.