# How much Amperage can pass through a BMS and DC stepup boost converter?

Tags: lithium-ion, step-up, bms

In my Mini UPS project for my router, I made a little circuit by using a 18650 li-ion battery charger module, a 3.7v /2800mAH li-ion battery, and the DC step-up boost converter. My router requires 9v/0.6A current. So once I connected this UPS for my router and switch it on and

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f46DtJ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

It seems quickly light up and disappear all lights in the router (Not working)

What i went wrong here? Have BMS or step-up converter a certain output power limit? Are my BMS, step-up converter, and or the battery not enough power to driving my router?

Comment: You haven't shown details of your step-up converter.

Comment: As Andy comments, we need **details**. Maybe you're using an unsuitable step-up converter. Maybe the battery is no good. Maybe... You can do basic trouble shooting, it is OK to, **as a test**, connect the battery directly to the boost converter. Does that work => then the BMS might not be OK. Does that also not work => battery and/or boost converter are not OK.

Comment: Yes they are limited in power, and 0.6A at 9V will need about 2A at 3.7V. The datasheets for those components will tell you those limits.

Comment: Thanks all for your support. I'll consider things that you tell

Comment: @Andyaka. I also don't know what is the specifications of my step-up converter. Cause I have a very little knowledge about electronics. I just go to the shop and bought it. How I find the details of the step-up converter. It seems there is no model number.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie I'll see

Comment: [What to check for when buying an electronic component or module](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/504044/what-to-check-for-when-buying-an-electronic-component-or-module).