# Where can I find how to use those rf transmitter/receiver

Tags: rf, pins, transmitter, receiver, arduino-uno

I bought those rf trans/receiver (GWB T400)
[image]

I figured out that the sck, miso and mosi are for the spi communication.
Gnd and 3v3 are pretty clear as well but I’m not sure what rst and cs are for.
I don’t know where to look for to learn how to use it with my arduino either.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: [What to check for when buying an electronic component or module](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/504044/what-to-check-for-when-buying-an-electronic-component-or-module)

Comment: You find out from the datasheet.  If the manufacturer doesn't provide one, look up the chip(s) on the board and find their datasheets.  Failing that, send then back and buy products with datasheets.

Comment: CS is also a signal necessary for SPI communication, much like SCK, MOSI, and MISO.

Comment: @nanofarad: what would CS would be for ?

Comment: It's the chip select.

Comment: @nanofarad: Is chip select and chip enable (CE) the same thing?

Comment: @Dominique Yes, they do the same thing. Read the part's datasheet for further details.

Comment: RST means reset. CS is not exactly as CE. It is used on SPI communication.

Answer (score 1):

From the ali pages, the chip seems to be an [LT8900](https://dtsheet.com/doc/434341/etc-lt8900) (Some ali vendors claim it has a NRF24L01, which I think is wrong. Check the marking on your modules.).

As you asked for info on how to use a SPI interface, I guess implementing a driver for this chip is way over your head. But [this guy](https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=324539.0) seems to have made and arduino driver for it, so you could try that.

Note that this is a 3.3V chip, so when you use a 5V arduino you will have to level-shift.

@nanofarad: I didn't check this chip, but radio chips often have both a CE pin that puts the chip in low-power mode, and a CS pin for the SPI interface. I think I recall a chip that, for greater confusion, swapped those pin names.