# What kind of FPC is this, and what should I couple it with?

Tags: stepper-motor, fpc

I'm working with [these planetary geared micro stepper motors](https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/Micro-Mini-4mm-2-phase-4-wire-Precision-Planetary-Gearbox-Gear-Stepper-Motor-PX/284233420749?hash=item422da1cfcd:g:heQAAOSwsCddrruR&var=585722994688) which come without a datasheet or any information from the sellers. I'm having a trouble figuring out how I should mate the FPC cable, can anyone tell me what kind of THT or SMD socket it'd fit?

Edit: This is for an academic research paper, and a researcher wants to use this motor because of it's small size. I know using ebay for component procurement is a horrid thing.

[image]

Comment: [What to check for when buying an electronic component or module](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/504044/what-to-check-for-when-buying-an-electronic-component-or-module). (or, you get what you pay for).

Comment: @Andyaka Unfortunately a researcher in my group insisted we use this motor in a prototype for a paper since it was very difficult finding a suitable alternative with better support (we needed the stepper to fit in a 4mm^2 space).

Comment: Anyone performing technical research should never use peebay for any reference material on system components. I suggest that they are not qualified to research what you should or shouldn't use. You can tell them that if you want.

Comment: @Andyaka I just pasted that over ;p If this was for anything other than one research paper then I would have refused the moment it went to ebay. Still though, it's peaked my interest in knowing what FPC cable that is, any ideas?

Comment: You could, on a whim, design mating PCB pads and use low-temp solder to reflow it together for a permanent, socket-less fit.

Comment: @rdtsc thanks, i thought about doing this, I didn't know FPC cables can take the heat. I'll make sure to use the low temp chipquik solder.

Comment: If the [cable](http://www-eng.lbl.gov/~shuman/NEXT/CURRENT_DESIGN/TP/MATERIALS/FFC_history.pdf) is [polyester](https://www.onlinetextileacademy.com/properties-of-polyester/) in base composition, it can take up to about 275°C. If [polyamide](https://aerosusa.com/applications-properties-and-uses-of-polyamide/), 500°C.  Low-melt solders go down to about 205°C I think (while maintaining significant strength.)

Comment: It's probably a custom fpc that is made for this motor only. You can easily find out the pins with a MM. The more important question is, how are you going to drive the motor?

Comment: You can solder fpc's like this with standard Sn/Pb solder if you're careful. Fine tip, finest solder you can find, and allow time to cool between each pad. Although, I'd just solder direct to the pins on the motor.

Comment: I've already soldered directly to the FPC and am using the motors fine, I want a nicer solution. Soldering directly to the pins was attempted but was slightly sketchy since it's just a plastic pole with the coil ends wrapped around.

Answer (score 0):

Look at:

1. JAE FA10 connectors family
2. Molex Flexi-Latch Right-Angle FPC-to-Board

I googled "motor fpc connector"