# Digital voltmeter reading half the voltage measured with Fluke multimeter

Tags: high-voltage, multimeter, voltage-measurement

I recently purchased these cheap [digital voltmeters](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00YALV0NG) from Amazon to display the output of my 2.5 kV HV supply. The HV supply has a dedicated 1/1000 output (0 - 2.5V)for monitoring, which I am trying to measure using the cheap voltmeter.

The voltmeter has 3 wires: +5V power, GND, and probe. Both the HV supply and voltmeter are powered by a single 5V supply. However, the voltmeter is consistently measuring half the actual value. When I measure the 1/1000 output with a Fluke multimeter (with other voltmeter disconnected) it measures the correct value.

I have tested the digital voltmeter with other benchtop supplies (5V, 12V, 15V) and it seems to work fine.
Any suggestions on what I could be missing here?

EDIT: The 1/1000 output shares ground with other HV supply inputs/outputs.

Comment: Your Fluke multimeter very likely has a standard 10 MEGohm input resistance. Amazon meter likely has less input resistance - perhaps due to the "calibration" potentiometer. The lower input resistance could cause a low reading compared with the Fluke.

Comment: What does the Fluke DVM measure when you connect both Fluke and other meter to the HV test point?  I suspect that the input resistance of the cheap DVM is much less than that of the Fluke meter, and is loading the HV test point, causing the low reading.

Comment: @PeterBennett With other meter connected, the Fluke measures half value as well.

Comment: [What to check for when buying an electronic component or module](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/504044/what-to-check-for-when-buying-an-electronic-component-or-module)

Comment: @All - FYI some comments were deleted here, after being flagged by other site members (or they were deleted because they made no sense, as they replied to now-deleted comments). Remember that condescending comments are *[not allowed](/help/conduct)* and they count towards possible future suspensions. Don't write comments that poke fun at someone or at their actions. Thanks.

Comment: I left a comment that became deleted and it wasn't condescending as far as I'm concerned. In fact it was common-sense to me. And this is a problem on this site that is annoying.

Comment: @Andyaka - "*I left a comment that became deleted and it wasn't condescending as far as I'm concerned*" Others *did* see it as condescending (and flagged it). As explained [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19756), discussion of behaviour or site policy should be on Meta, so please raise a new topic on Meta. Once you ask there, we can repost your comment (and other examples of previous flagged comments to give context) and discuss them.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The input impedance of those modules is in the 100K range- they use a divider directly into the ADC input of a microcontroller, as opposed to multimeters which are 10M\$\Omega\$ down to maybe 1M\$\Omega\$ for some cheap handheld meters. Since it reads about half, that implies the output resistance of the HV unit is also around 100K\$\Omega\$ and you need a 10M\$\Omega\$ or higher input resistance to get an accurate reading.

You can either buffer the input with an op-amp or you can get a meter module that has a 10M\$\Omega\$ input resistance.

Eg. [MCP601](https://www.alliedelec.com/m/d/1e468013d32487cc03053aab0ce584de.pdf)

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2foNiQN.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: I tried buffering with a TL072 that I had lying around, and that seems to have done it. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

You need to know more about the 1/1000 output (0 - 2.5V)for monitoring. Is it a resistive voltage divider and what resistors are used?

What is the input resistance of the Fluke multimeter and what of the cheap voltmeter?

The input resistance of the cheap voltmeter is too low, the load for the monitor output is too much and that is why the measured voltage is too low.