# LiPo battery choke and cutoff momentarily when connected to heavy load

Tags: power, batteries, power-electronics, lipo

I bought a couple of this [lipo](https://www.amazon.eg/-/en/lipo-Battery-1000mAH-without-Connector/dp/B0B86CZ1K1/ref=asc_df_B0B86CZ1K1/?tag=egoshpadde-21&linkCode=df0&hvadid=544930982097&hvpos=&hvnetw=g&hvrand=975876244334998283&hvpone=&hvptwo=&hvqmt=&hvdev=c&hvdvcmdl=&hvlocint=&hvlocphy=9112370&hvtargid=pla-1922027187512&psc=1) batteries it outputs a 4.2 V when fully charged nicely but trying to use it with coreless motors that draws about 3 A of current each, the battery just gives a surge of current on contact and then shuts the current off the motor doesn't spin but for a short surge and then stops completely.

The problem is not with the motor asserted by connecting it to a power supply and it works fine.

So why does the battery cuts off the current.
I was hoping to continuously draw about 12-14 A out of two of this batteries for 4 motors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *so why does the battery cuts off the current*

You appear to have bought a LiPo battery from an unreliable site that reports no customer reviews, gives no authentic manufacturing information ("generic" is the stated source) and doesn't state the maximum output current. Nor does the unreliable site have a link to a data sheet.

There is even a customer question that asks this: -

> **The battery number in the picture doesn't match the info in the page,
> which one is right?**

The given answer is this: -

> **it is not the same shape or dimensions**

Maybe you should read this Q and A: [What to check for when buying an electronic component or module](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/504044/what-to-check-for-when-buying-an-electronic-component-or-module).

Comment: can I just remove the protection circuit and use it as normal 18650 cell (without any bms ) or  just throw it away ?
 I am assuming the small protection circuit in there is responsible for this cutoff

Comment: I think you cannot use it and it's too dangerous to use modified. You have really got to "be on your guard" for amazon (and many others) when buying anything electrical.